# Use the ASNetworkImageNode to load the https image ？

Tags: ios, asyncdisplaykit

I am using HTTP with `ASNetworkImageNode` to load the image normally and now replace it with HTTPS, my HTTPS is using a self-signed certificate.

Using `ASNetworkImageNode` it can not load.

I was wondering how to configure the normal loading of my photos.

Comment: Not sure its related with ASNetworkImageNode about. Do you try load that image by urself https with NSURLSession? Its looks like your configure App Transport Security (ATS) is wrong.

Comment: I can use SDWebimage to load pictures. In my project ASNetworkImageNode can meet my current needs, so I do not know how to configure ASNetworkImageNode configure App Transport Security (ATS)

Comment: Is SDWebimage work fine with your cert? Or maybe you can share simple project?

Comment: Please describe what happens when "it can not load". Are there any errors or how is the current behavior changed after switching to HTTPS?

Comment: I can use SDWebimage to load the https format image, I would like to be asyncdisplaykit using the https self-signed certificate

Comment: Can you show your construct of `ASNetworkImageNode`?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code snippet for loading image from a url using **ASNetworkImageNode**

```
fileprivate var imageNode : ASNetworkImageNode = ASNetworkImageNode()
fileprivate var imageUrl = "your image url" // you can put your image url here.

addSubnode(imageNode) // adding the node to the parent node.

imageNode.url = URL.init(string: imageUrl!)
imageNode.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
imageNode.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
```